# creating table result in errno 150

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to create the following schema, but I'm getting errors when I'm trying to create project and staffphone tables.

Not sure what is it complaining about.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE staff(
-> StaffID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
-> FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
-> LastName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
-> Address VARCHAR(30) ,
-> City VARCHAR(15) ,
-> State VARCHAR(3) ,
-> Position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
-> Wage INT NOT NULL
-> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE projects (
-> StaffID INT NOT NULL,
-> ProjectName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
-> Allocation INT NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, ProjectName) ,
-> FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE
-> );
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'staff.projects' (errno: 150)

mysql> CREATE TABLE staffphone (
-> StaffID INT NOT NULL,
-> PhoneNumber VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, PhoneNumber) ,
-> FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE
-> );
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'staff.staffphone' (errno: 150)
mysql>
```

Any idea would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: The table is named `staff` but you have `REFERENCES Staff`. Is this in Linux? Read this: **[Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)**

Comment: I have alterd the table and changes staff to Staff as you noted, and it worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ypercube you hit the nail right on the head. Post it as an answer !!!

Comment: @Deano, I would keep all the table names in lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was stated in the comments by @yercube, you have a case sensitivity issue.

## SOLUTION #1

Create the first table with the name `Staff`

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
   StaffID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   FirstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   LastName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   Address VARCHAR(30) ,
   City VARCHAR(15) ,
   State VARCHAR(3) ,
   Position VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   Wage INT NOT NULL
);
```

Then, create the other two tables. It should work.

## SOLUTION #2 (based on @ypercube's suggestion)

Keep the table `staff`, but create the other two like this:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    StaffID INT NOT NULL,
    ProjectName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Allocation INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, ProjectName) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );

CREATE TABLE staffphone (
    StaffID INT NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, PhoneNumber) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

## Give it a Try !!!